# How do i add 2 divs in document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

So. This is my problem. I´m going to add a modal to my website that can be toggled by at least 20 buttons, but it´s not going to be the same modal, they have different content.

I tried this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn,myBtn2");
```

1 button toggles the modal by pressing "myBtn", and the secound button cant have the same id, because then only 1 pops up. Code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn""myBtn2");


var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
 }
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 10; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

.close {
color: #aaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

 .close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="btn-more" id="myBtn">Open Modal</div>
```

Here is the full demo:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: I think that you meant to tag this question for JavaScript and not Java. I've fixed this for you, and please let me know if I made this change in error.

Comment: getElementById returns a single item, not an array.

Comment: Then how do i make a few more modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".toToggle");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++){
btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML += "<span class='close'>&times;</span><p>Some text in the Modal.. giv by button with id="+this.id+"</p>";
  var numId = (this.id).replace("myBtn","");
  if(numId == 0) {
    document.querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML += "<div class='imblock'><img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/28993/pexels-photo.jpg'/></div>";
    }
   else if(numId == 1) {
    document.querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML += "<div class='imblock'><img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/50704/car-race-ferrari-racing-car-pirelli-50704.jpeg'/></div>";
    }
   else if(numId == 2) {
    document.querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML += "<div class='imblock'><img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4-PDH6sKsA0/hqdefault.jpg'/></div>";
    }
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
      document.querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML = "";}
});
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      document.querySelector(".modal-content").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.imblock img{
  width:400px;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0:
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="toToggle" id="myBtn0">Open Modal-0</button>
<button class="toToggle" id="myBtn1">Open Modal-1</button>
<button class="toToggle" id="myBtn2">Open Modal-2</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How can i add content to each of them?

Comment: well it's in the answer. you see in the `for` loop where I add content through `.innerHTML += ` . I just added a line. Same way you can any common content and you can show specific content like the way I showed id of that button using switch  or an if statement

Comment: ok. I updated my answer and included images for each modal. and please don't forget to accept the answer. you know click on the checkmark on the left of my answer.

Comment: okay, done. I updated my answer. let me know if there's anything else.